# Type inference for generic strategy pattern in Scala

Tags: scala, oop, generics, type-inference

**What I would like to accomplish**

I want to utilize a strategy pattern, whereas the strategy class has type parameters.

**What the code looks like**

Assume I have the following generic abstract strategy class:

```
abstract class Strategy[T, V]() {
    def doSomething(x: Int): V
    def unDoSomething(x: V): T
}
```

I now derive two concrete strategies:

```
class StrategyOne() extends Strategy[Int, String] {
    def doSomething(x: Int): String = { x.toString() }
    def unDoSomething(x: String): Int = { x.toInt }
}


class StrategyTwo() extends Strategy[Double, List[Int]] {
    def doSomething(x: Int): List[Int] = { List(x, 10, 20)}
    def unDoSomething(x: List[Int]): Double= { x.reduceLeft(_ + _) + 0.1 }
}
```

Now, we have a class which uses the strategy:

```
class Worker[T, V](strategy: Strategy[T, V]) { 
    def run() {
        val res = strategy.doSomething(5) //res is a T
        val res2 = strategy.unDoSomething(res) //res2 is a V
        println(res2)
    }

}
```

As expected, I am now able to instantiate new workers with out explicit types:

```
val worker1 = new Worker(new StrategyOne())
val worker2 = new Worker(new StrategyTwo())
```

**Problem**

However, I also want to make use of some kind of dynamic strategy selection, like this:

```
val strategies = Map("one" -> new StrategyOne(), "two" -> new StrategyTwo())
val worker = new Worker(strategies(args(0)))
```

Naturally, the compiler tells me that what I want is impossible, because no type can be inferred.

**Question**

I know that this constellation is unfortunate, but I need the types of `T` and `V` inside `Worker`. 
Is it possible to make this kind of pattern work for this specific case?

Comment: I just took your code, copy pasted it into a worksheet. With a few very minor adjustments, it seems to work and I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.

Could you provide the actual errors from the compiler? (code I tested is at https://gist.github.com/agenovese/82dc31743641f059adf2, too long for a comment and not really an answer so I linked it)

Comment: @AngeloGenovese, thank you. Plase try it with using all values inside the functions in StrategyOne and StrategyTwo. I'll update the question.

Comment: Also, I re-checked my example in REPL, and in this case, it indeed compiles. But notice that the types of the map strategies become for example `_ >: Double with Int <: AnyVal`. This is what breaks my code in the long run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract type members should help you more than type parameters, here. Indeed, you mostly want to pass around `Strategy`s without caring too much about their two types (including putting them in a map). And at one point (in the `Worker`), you need the types.

So I suggest the following (you should probably give more descriptive names to `V` and `T` in this model, but I couldn't figure out what they meant so I left them as is):

```
abstract class Strategy {
  type T
  type V

  def doSomething(x: Int): V
  def unDoSomething(x: V): T
}

class StrategyOne extends Strategy {
  type T = Int
  type V = String
  def doSomething(x: Int): String = {...}
  def unDoSomething(x: String): Int = {...}
}

class StrategyTwo extends Strategy {
  type T = Double
  type V = List[Int]
  def doSomething(x: Int): List[Int] = {...}
  def unDoSomething(x: List[Int]): Double= {...}
}

class Worker(strategy: Strategy) { 
  def run(): Unit = {
    val res = strategy.doSomething(5) //res is a strategy.T
    val res2 = strategy.unDoSomething(res) //res2 is a strategy.V
    println(res2)
  }
}
```

In this case, the types of `res` and `res2` are inferred. But should you need to write their types down, they are `strategy.T` and `strategy.V`, as I wrote in the comments (path-dependent types, if you want to Google the concept).

You will still be able to create your strategies easily:

```
val worker1 = new Worker(new StrategyOne)
val worker2 = new Worker(new StrategyTwo)
```

and now you can also do this:

```
val strategies = Map("one" -> new StrategyOne, "two" -> new StrategyTwo)
val worker = new Worker(strategies(args(0)))
```

as you requested. And it'll all typecheck nicely.

Comment: in your Worker example, it should be: `val res = strategy.doSomething(5)`, etc

Comment: I did not know that this was possible. The Scala language never fails to astonish me.